# How do I interpret this particular feature

Tags: featuretools

lets say I have 3 entities: parent1 <- child -> parent2. I used `dfs()` and got feature I can't understand `MEAN(child.parent2.MEAN(child.num_feature))`. Reading documentation I thought about `any_entity.MEAN` features as "group by entity then apply MEAN" but now this approach doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep Feature Synthesis creates new features by "stacking" existing features. To understand this feature, let’s go through how this is calculated step-by-step.

1. Calculate feature `MEAN(child.num_feature)` and add it to `parent2`.
2. Join that feature (defined on `parent2`) into  `child`. This creates a new feature `parent2.MEAN(child.num_feature)` defined on `child`. Rows of `child` that have the same value for `parent2 will have the same value for this feature.
3. Group the `child` by `parent` and take the mean of that feature. This creates `MEAN(child.parent2.MEAN(child.num_feature))`

To help clarify, let's go through a concrete example

Imagine `parent1` was a table of customers, `child` was a table of `transactions` by your customers with the column `amount`, and `parent2` was a table of each unique product you sell.

The feature `MEAN(transactions.product.SUM(amount))` created for the customers entity could be interpreted as “what is the average total sales of products this customer purchased” e.g “does this customer buy products that have sold a lot”.